# Send Javascript and HTML in http response in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to send two responses for a javascript file and a html file but the client isn't receiving either. Why is the client not receiving the html and javascript files? I'm using Nodejs, javascript, and html.

server.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

// use createReadStream instead to save memory
const index = fs.readFileSync('www/index.html');
const java = fs.readFileSync('javascript.js');

// this is our request handler
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.end(index);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.end(java);
  //res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>
        <p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>
        <button type="button" onclick='changeme()'>Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript.js

```
function changeme() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"
}
```

Comment: Can't call `end()` twice. Also, if you want to link to a JavaScript file from your HTML, you have to make it so that your server sends that JavaScript file when it's requested. Can't just dump anything in one response body and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying that it's in the same directory as your server.js file, i.e.

`const java = fs.readFileSync('./javascript.js');`

It seems that there's a problem finding the file, this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/serving-static-files-in-nodejs) should help you with this issue. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try out

```
const fs = require("fs");
const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;

// use createReadStream instead to save memory
const index = fs.readFileSync("index.html");
const java = fs.readFileSync("javascript.js");

// this is our request handler
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 if (req.url === "/") {
   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
   res.write(index);
 }
 if (req.url === "/javascript.js") {
   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
   res.write(java);
 }
 res.statusCode = 200;
 //   res.writeHead(200, java);
 res.end();
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
 console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```